Not able to access minio on browser deployed on kubernetes through nodeport
I have deployed minio on kubernetes with service (nodeport) and deployment using PV and PVCs and I am not able to access it from the browser. I have to use NodePort only that is a constraint.
All the pods are running successfully including the service, PV and PVC.
I tried with minikube tunneling, but it keeps changing the IP so caanot use that. I used it with

"http://(minikube IP):(Port)"

also, but it doesnt work.

The problem is that minio assigns random port to webui if not specified.
So, here's how I fixed it.
  containers:
    - name: minio
      image: minio/minio:latest
      args:
        - server 
        - /data 
        - --console-address=0.0.0.0:9090 <-- this makes the difference
      ports:
        - containerPort: 9000 # API port
        - containerPort: 9090 # WebUI port

then add a service to expose the port 9000 and 9090
